# Flex 3: Rollout/RollOver event dispatching problem

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I'm making a right toolbar with different buttons on it. When i rollover it, it slides inside the view and when i rollout it slides out of the view almost 90%. each button on it also has some rollOver/Out event listeners. 
Problem is, when i rollover on any button, then the rollout event of the container(toolbar) get dispatched and toolbar hides itself.

Is there any way to keep hide/showing on rollover/rollout the toolbar, and also justify with buttons over the toolbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had this problem in Flash I listened to MouseMoved event and checked the x and y of the mouse. If you use this technique for your toolbar, you can go ahead and use the RollOver/Out for the buttons. But maybe you can solve it easier in Flex which I don't know of.

[Here's](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=302928) your solution I think, with the mouseChildren property.

Comment: thanks, i also did it using mouseX-MouseY position calculation, but i want to confirm if it is the best way to do that. and i think it is :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to stop an EventListener from being called (and it seems like that is your issue), the easiest way is to call

```
event.stopImmediatePropegation()
```

You may have to couple it with adding a priority parameter to addEventListener:

```
                                                        // capture
target.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 1000 );
                                                                // priority
```

The trick is to make sure that you have the MenuButtons use a higher priority than the Menu itself, that way you can prevent the Menu from listening to the Menu Buttons.

Comment: I don't think that's his question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is his question, but I think that it is the root of the problem he is trying to solve.